# Opencv C++ "VideoCapture.open()" is always returning false in Android (Xamarin Android)

Tags: android, opencv, xamarin.android

After making an Object and initializing it with the path of mpej/avi/mp4, I am always getting "false" in "obj.isOpened()". Always getting the false flag in it no matter what you put in open function as input parameter. I am working in Xamarin Android. The code is pretty straight forward but I have no idea why it is not working.

**Using the following tools:**

**1)** VS2017

**2)** Xamarin Android (Binding OpenCV project with Xamarin Android App. Used this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFv_1KeMZVs)

**3)** Opencv c++ 4.0.1-1.4.4,jar

**I have tried the following**

**1)** Give all permissions from Android Manifest

**2)** Used following as input parameters

```
**a)** Link

**b)** 0    ,  -1   , 2......5000

**c)** Local file from assets folder as well as Resource-> Drawable folder
```

**3)** Tried different formats (mp4, Mpeg, Avi). None worked.

**4)** Imported "FFmpeg-2.1 -1.4.4.jar" in the binding project. It didn't work.

**5)** Downloaded Opencv Sample Project(version= 3.1.0) and ran my code in the project. It didn't work.

**Code:**

```
string Video_Path = ("android.resource://" + this.PackageName +"/" + Resource.Drawable.sample2);
VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
bool flag=capture.Open(Video_Path);
if (capture.IsOpened)
{
}
else
{
}
```

**Note:** In the above code sample2 is my mpej/mp4/avi file.
OpenCV is working fine because I have tested my code by converting an image to grayscale and it worked.